# adf v2 linked service connection pooling

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am connecting azure sql server using adfv2 linked service.
I am getting below error

> "Execution fail against sql server. Sql error number: 10928. Error
>   Message: Resource ID : 1. The request limit for the database is 120
>   and has been reached. See
>   'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267637' for assistance

Does linked service support the connection pooling and if yes then how to implement the same?
if you have better option to resolve the issue without any  sql server configuration changes Please guide me

Comment: Hi ram. I have never heard about such a feature in ADF. As you probably know, the request limit is related to a pricing tier for the database (Standard/S2 has 120 max concurrent logins). One of the option you might consider is to scale database up before connect to and down afterwards. Not very pretty solution though.  More options:  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/latam/2015/06/01/how-to-deal-with-the-limits-of-azure-sql-database-maximum-logins/

Comment: Hi ram,If my answer is helpful for you, you can vote it or accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is very clear: "1. The request limit for the database is 120 and has been reached." 
[image]

For more details, please see :

1. [Resource limits for single databases using the DTU-based purchasing
   model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits-single-databases).
2. [SQL Database resource limits for Azure SQL Database server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-resource-limits-database-server)

To solve this error, you need to [Scale single database resources in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-single-database-scale).

Here is another blog can help you: [How to deal with the limits of Azure SQL Database maximum logins](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/latam/2015/06/01/how-to-deal-with-the-limits-of-azure-sql-database-maximum-logins/).

Hope this helps.